# Delete a record from a table that doesn't exist in another

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tbl_Imbalances that I would like to "synchronize" with a query of same records called UNDEFINED_EXECUTION.  I want to make sure 3 fields match to qualify i.e funds_center, SAG, MDEP, COST_COLLECTOR.  But I can't seem to get even one attempt to work.

I've currently tried DELETE tbl_IMBALANCES* cost_collector from tbl_IMBALANCES Where cost_collector not in (select cost_collector from undefined_execution) it should delete one record since it doesn't exist in the "undefined execution" query but it doesn't delete anything.

Comment: I recreated your query and it worked for me, so the logic seems correct. Is there anything you're missing? Is cost_collector the same variable type for both undefined_execution and tbl_imbalances (text vs. memo for example)

Comment: Thank you for confirming.  Yes it does work. I accidentally referred to a different imbalances table.